# Antlr4 partially matches but does not report an error

Tags: token, antlr, antlr4, rules

here is my antlr4 grammar:

```
grammar TestExpr;

prog: stat ;

stat: expr
    ;

expr : expr '|' expr #orJoin
     | expr '&' expr  #andJoin
     | '(' expr ')'  #nested
     | KEY '=' value  #kv
     ;
value: KEY | VALUE;

KEY : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_-]* ;
VALUE: [a-zA-Z0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9._-]* ;
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

If "a233=A(" is entered, only "a233=A" can be matched. I expected it to report an error, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `prog` rule to be:

```
prog: stat EOF;
```

ANTLR, by default, will match the longest valid sequence of characters that match your grammar.  This also means it will quit parsing when something ceases to "work", if everything up to that point is valid (even if more input is present but leaves the parse in an incomplete state).

By adding the `EOF` rule, you're saying that your "rule" is that it must match ALL the input (including the `EOF`) so you won't encounter this problem.  Because of this it's considered a best practice to have any rules that should parse all input end with an `EOF` token.

Comment: Now I have another problem. The above program can transform "A! =1&b=2 "is interpreted as" A =1&b=2 ", but this is not expected

Comment: Currently I can do this by adding an ErrorListener to the Lexer, but is this standard practice

Comment: Don't ask additional questions in your original question. Instead open a new one.